# Read all .txt files in a folder line by line

Tags: java, multithreading, csv, bufferedreader, filereader

Right now I'm working on a thread that constantly looks for .txt files on a folder. Once it finds a file, it's supposed to read the content, line by line, (using a buffered reader and split (separator) to finally insert this data into a database).

Thing is before my code was looking for a specific file with a specific name, and it worked perfectly, but then my professor told me that the program needs to look for any .txt file on the folder. So I added some code to do this and tried to make it work with my old code.

I think what is not working are the following lines:

- `FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileList[i]);`
- `BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(fr);`

Error I'm getting is the catch - File not found exception e.

Okay, here's my code! :D

```
public void run() {

    while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20000);

            boolean flag = false;

            try {

                FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
                    public boolean accept(File dir, String fileName) {
                        return fileName.endsWith("txt");
                    }
                };

                File f = new File("D:\\Mis Documentos\\");
                String[] fileList = f.list(filter);
                for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {

                     System.out.println(fileList[i]);
                    FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileList[i]);
                    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(fr);
                    String cadena = b.readLine();
                    Validaciones v = new Validaciones();

                    if (cadena == null) {

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El fichero está vacío");

                    } else {

                        while (cadena != null) {

                            String[] fields = cadena.split(SEPARATOR);

                            EntidadDAO ed = new EntidadDAODB();
                            Entidad ent = new Contacto();

                            if (fields.length == 7) {

                                // System.out.println("fields es 7");
                                for (int i2 = 0; i2 < fields.length; i2++) {

                                    nombre = fields[0];
                                    apellido = fields[1];
                                    alias = fields[2];
                                    direccion = fields[3];
                                    telefono = fields[4];
                                    nacimiento = fields[5];
                                    email = fields[6];

                                }

                                if (v.validarThread(nacimiento, email, telefono) == true) {

                                    System.out.println("El contacto " + nombre + " se validó correctamente");
                                } else {

                                    System.out.println("No se pudo cargar el contacto " + nombre + ". Error al validar los datos.");
                                    cadena = b.readLine();
                                    continue;

                                }

                            ((Contacto) ent).setNombre(nombre);
                            ((Contacto) ent).setApellido(apellido);
                            ((Contacto) ent).setAlias(alias);
                            ((Contacto) ent).setDireccion(direccion);
                            ((Contacto) ent).setTelefono(telefono);
                            ((Contacto) ent).setNacimiento(nacimiento);
                            ((Contacto) ent).setEmail(email);
                            ((Contacto) ent).setFavorito("no");
                            // System.out.println(ent.toString());
                            //  ed.agregarEntidad(ent);
                            cadena = b.readLine();

                            } else {

                                System.out.println("No se pudo cargar el contacto " + nombre + ". Faltan datos.");
                                cadena = b.readLine();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    b.close();
                    //      moverFichero();
                } // aca termina el for que lee cada archivo txt.

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                System.out.println("No se encontró el fichero");

            } catch (Exception e) {

                System.out.println("Ocurrió un error al leer o cerrar el fichero" + e);

            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            System.out.println("Error al ejecutar thread");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have my PC with me to troubleshoot your code at the moment; however, try changing line String cadena = b.readLine(); as String = ""; Then on line while (cadena != null) { , please try changing it to while (String cadena = b.readline()) != null) {.

Comment: It appears you have a lot of cadena = b.readLine(); in your code which could be removed. Did you try adding a break point to where you think the error is and stepping through the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are passing only file name for `FileReader`

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileList[i]);
```

Give complete path of that file

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("D:\\Mis Documentos\\"+fileList[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked perfectly! Now I can move on with the code. Thanks!!